# Coffeescript: conditional value one-liner

Tags: coffeescript

Can this be turned into a snazzy one-liner?

```
thing = thing2 / 32 * 100 * 100
thing = 0 unless thing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately coffeescript doesn't support ternary operator. But you can write:

```
@zoomGlobal = if @position.ratio then @position.ratio / 32 * 100 * 100 else 0
```

Or

```
@zoomGlobal = @position.ratio / 32 * 100 * 100 || @zoomGlobal
```

[Here example](http://goo.gl/FV7qS)

Answer (score 2):

if you are confident that @position.ratio is always set as a number, you could just have:

```
@zoomGlobal = @position.ration / 32 * 100 * 100
```

soon you should be able to use the new ** operator

```
@zoomGlobal = @position.ration / 32 * 100 ** 2
```

if @position.ration might not exist then use what Ivan suggested:

```
@zoomGlobal = if @position.ratio then @position.ratio / 32 * 100 * 100 else 0
```

also, I can't see from your example what the context is but note that

```
10 / 2 * 2 * 2 == 20
```

while

```
10 / (2 * 2 * 2) == 1.25
```

Comment: What's the double asterisk operator you're referring to?

Comment: @Sandro: Exponentiation, presumably. I.e., `100 ** 2 === 100 * 100 === Math.pow(100, 2)`.

Comment: it will be included in the next CoffeeScript release i believe